# Apply \widetext in Lyx only to equation and not whole paragraph

Tags: equations, lyx, revtex

I am writing a document in the revtex4-1 class in LyX. I would like to apply `widetext` to some of my longer formulas. However, selecting the `widetext` environment in Lyx would cause the entire paragraph to switch to a single column, including all regular text, instead of just the equation. How would I target the equation specifically?

Answer (score 6):

1. Hit enter to start a new paragraph.
2. Add the widetext environment
3. Add equation inside widetext enviroment.

Another option could be using ERTs for starting and ending the environment:

1. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to open an ERT, and write `\begin{widetext}` in it.
2. Hit <kbd>→</kbd>, the right arrow key, to move the cursor outside the ERT.
3. Start a displayed math env with for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, and write your equation.
4. Hit <kbd>→</kbd>, the right arrow key, to move the cursor outside the math inset.
5. Without hitting enter or anything, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to open a second ERT, and write `\end{widetext}` in it.
6. Continue the sentence immediately after the ERT, no space, no line feed.

Here is what it might look like in LyX, and the code it generates:

[image]

You could also add a newline inside the ERTs, before `\begin{widetext}` and after `\end{widetext}`. It wouldn't make a new paragraph, but it would place those on their own lines of code.

Comment: I'd rather not go that route. Syntactically, there is a reason that text and equations are grouped together in a single paragraph. For example, day I would like to write: "... are related by Einstein's famous formula, $$E=mc^2,$$ where $c$ is the speed of light."

Comment: @BenjiRemez Looking at the generated code, you don't actually get a paragraph break before the widetext, though you do get one after. Using ERTs to start and end the widetext might be an option, I'll edit in a bit. (Completely unrelated: if you find yourself writing LaTeX code, don't use `$$ ... $$` for displaymath, cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Comment: Yes, I was thinking along the lines of manual ERTs, but I just wondered if there might be a more elegant solution than that.